# The meaning of stressing the word "is"

Tags: meaning, auxiliary-verbs

> This *is* strange!

Does this mean, "It is really strange!" or "This, as in **This**, not any other is strange!"
Or both?

Comment: Kinda seems like you're more concerned with the meaning of "This" than of "is"...Incidentally, the meaning of "is" has received [some pretty high-profile debate](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/chatterbox/1998/09/bill_clinton_and_the_meaning_of_is.html) in the legal context ;)

Comment: You could ask more generally about sentences with **stressed auxiliaries**.  The contrast between "This is strange" and "This ***is*** strange" is the same contrast found between "I like pears" and "I ***do*** like pears", and between "I've taken the trash out" and "I ***have*** taken the trash out."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spoken language, it depends on which word you stress.

> THIS is strange.

It is this thing that is strange, not some other thing.

> This IS strange.

I wasn't sure if it was strange or not at first, but now I conclude that it is. Or you say that it isn't strange, but I insist that it is. Or, in context, may mean that it is strange in the present, as opposed to the past or future. Like, "That was strange", Sally said. "No," Bob replied, "that IS strange."

> This is STRANGE.

It is not just a little strange, but really really strange. Or, one might think that it is something else, but the correct description is strange.

There's an old joke about a man who suddenly becomes very rich. Someone asks him if the money has changed him. "Well, I guess it has in some ways," he replies. "Now I'm eccentric, when I used to be strange. And I'm delightfully witty, when I used to be rude."

In written English, we might indicate the emphasis with upper case (like I did here) or italics or bold or some other typographical convention, but it's more common to add some words to make it clear.

Comment: RE: _"it's more common to add some words to make it clear..."_ You are certainly right about that! In fact, it would be rather unexpected to find just those three words by themselves, with no other surrounding context. Now that **would** be strange!